# Responsive Grid

Tags: html, css

How can I make a responsive CSS grid such that the 2nd and 4th column will be hidden below 1280px, the cells are filled with images (object-fit), the size of individual items depends on the total width of the whole gird and there is gap of 20px. Ideally below 780px all images are in one row. See the picture below.

[image]

```css
  .gallery{
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows:  repeat(2, 1fr);
  }

  .gallery > * {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }

  .gallery img:nth-child(1){
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }


  .gallery img:nth-child(9){
    grid-column: 4 / span 2;
  }

  img{
    height: calc((100vw - 4 * 20px) / 6);
  }


  @media screen and (max-width: 1279px) {

    .gallery{
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows:  repeat(2, 1fr);
    }


    .gallery img:nth-child(1){
      grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    }

    .gallery img:nth-child(9){
      grid-column: 3 / span 2;
    }


    .gallery img:nth-child(2),
    .gallery img:nth-child(5),
    .gallery img:nth-child(8),
    .gallery img:nth-child(10){
      display: none;
    }

    img{
      height: calc( (100vw - 3*20px) / 4);
    }

  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $extra-small-device){
    .gallery {
      margin: 15px;
      width: 90vw;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;

      display: flex;
      gap: 20px;
    }

    .gallery img {
      object-fit: unset;
      width: calc(70vw)!important;
      height: calc(70vw)!important;
    }


  }
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
    <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'/>
   </div>
```

Edit: I want the size of the wide rectangles to be based on the squares and the gap of the grid.

In the example, the "squares" are taller

Comment: put your html, pls

Comment: So you want the wide rectangles to be the width of two of your smaller rectangles plus the padding in between? Also, in terms of the remaining images, you want those placed behind the other images, is display critical to those remaining images?

Comment: Okey I almost got it, see the snippet. The only problem remaining is the use of VW instead of 100% in the image height calculation.